# VS2017: Linker errors after enabling MASM in C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, masm

So I'm trying to create a .dll wrapper (32 bit x86) in C++ and I need to write assembler wrapper functions. I've tried to use inline assembler in combination with __declspec(naked) but that didn't seem to work for C++ constructors (the compiler still generated code).

I've tried to work around that by writing with raw assembler files directly.
Before doing anything with MASM (and invoking any of my assembler functions) my project compiles and links fine.
In order to be able to use MASM I went into the "Build Customizations" and enabled MASM. After doing that I now get a bunch of linker errors with seemingly unrelated functions:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _memset  SoundEngine D:\Home\Documents\Git\SoundEngine\SoundEngine\MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj)   1   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _free    SoundEngine D:\Home\Documents\Git\SoundEngine\SoundEngine\MSVCRT.lib(delete_scalar.obj) 1   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __cexit  SoundEngine D:\Home\Documents\Git\SoundEngine\SoundEngine\MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj)   1   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CxxThrowException@8    SoundEngine D:\Home\Documents\Git\SoundEngine\SoundEngine\MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj)   1
```

Since those aren't even in refrenced (at least directly) in my code, how do I make this error go away?

Does VS change any name mangling or linker options after enabling MASM?

Comment: This won't change a thing, but you may get more information from the complete build output in the Output tab. Usually that's a few tabs away from the Error List. Error List's job it to present simplified information quickly and some problems just aren't simple enough. Plus the Output tab is raw text that's much easier to read when pasted into a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any additional information there. Definitely the preferred way for pasting these though. I'll remember that.